# When to ditch LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

LINQ just seems to generate horrendously optimised SQL (in general). I can write way more efficient T-SQL myself.

Do huge websites with my thousands of daily visitors use LINQ? Or should LINQ at some point be ditched? And if so, with what? and when?

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using when you're seeing the "horrendously optimised SQL"?

Comment: personally I don't like LINQ, because I like to take full control of what I want to read from the DB or what I want to write.

Comment: Your question seems off-topic for SO. Maybe it is more suitable for the http://programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Me too Steve... I'm using LINQ because I want to go into Contracting next year, and "LINQ" seems to come up on job searches.

Comment: i read in a question around here somewhere that this sight uses LinqtoSQL but personally I would call from stored procedures in t-sql if possible.

Comment: LINQ To SQL and Dapper are used with Stack overflow (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10370/181661)

Answer (score 6):

> Do huge websites with my thousands of daily visitors use LINQ?

Yes. Why not? Most SQL is trivial and you can always fall back to a stored procedure where it matters.

And that is the point. Let LINQ handlethe easy 80% and focus on the more complex.

And ther rest you handle by not talking to the database - caching is not that hard to plan for.

Comment: +1 for caching.  That's a bigger performance boost than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

What I have done with my apps, when L2S or EF creates inefficient T-SQL is to create a view that does exactly what I want, in an efficient manner and I just have L2S or EF query the view.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this website (stackoverflow) uses linq2sql extensively, although I believe they are using a micro-orm (sqlfu?) for some of the heavier taks..

Comment: They created and use dapper: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net